# C++ - Makefile using g++

Tags: c++, makefile, g++

I have made a Makefile for my CMSC 202 course project, 'Blackjack'. It does everything I need it to and it works perfectly. You may be asking why I posted here then, this is because I have no idea how it works and I didn't use any other resources but myself to create it.

Here is my Makefile code.

```
# Object files to either reference or create                          
OBJECTS = Proj2.o Blackjack.o Deck.o Card.o Hand.o Player.o           
# The executable file that will be created at the end                 
EXEC = Proj2.out                                                      
# The flags to use for compilation                                    
FLAGS = -Wall                                                         
# The code compiler to use for compilation                            
CC = g++                                                              

# Perform action on all object files (May or may not exist)           
all: $(OBJECTS)                                                       
        $(CC) $(FLAGS) -o $(EXEC) $(OBJECTS)
```

Here is the terminal output when I call `make` in the terminal.

```
g++    -c -o Proj2.o Proj2.cpp
g++    -c -o Blackjack.o Blackjack.cpp
g++    -c -o Deck.o Deck.cpp
g++    -c -o Card.o Card.cpp
g++    -c -o Hand.o Hand.cpp
g++    -c -o Player.o Player.cpp
g++ -Wall -o Proj2.out Proj2.o Blackjack.o Deck.o Card.o Hand.o Player.o
```

Can anyone tell me how the .o files are being compiled? It does not look like they are being prompted to be compiled with that `g++ -c -o $.o $.cpp` command anywhere in the Makefile. Nor did I state to use any .cpp files.

Thank you in advance for your help.

### Edit

Thanks to all your great help, this is now the terminal output I receive when using make.

```
g++ -Wall   -c -o Proj2.o Proj2.cpp
g++ -Wall   -c -o Blackjack.o Blackjack.cpp
g++ -Wall   -c -o Deck.o Deck.cpp
g++ -Wall   -c -o Card.o Card.cpp
g++ -Wall   -c -o Hand.o Hand.cpp
g++ -Wall   -c -o Player.o Player.cpp
g++ -Wall -o Proj2.out Proj2.o Blackjack.o Deck.o Card.o Hand.o Player.o
```

Thank you so much to all of you who have contributed.

Comment: You're -Wall flag isn't working by the way, you can see it's not being passed to g++ when compiling, which is when you need it.

Comment: ...and putting it in `CFLAGS` instead of `FLAGS` fixes it. (Although it should be `CXXFLAGS`, and `CXX`, as it's C++, not C... strange.)

Comment: Thanks for the CXXFLAGS tip! Everything works even better now, the compiler links the CXXFLAGS just like you said :)

Comment: Will changing CC to CXX make the Makefile use the compiler linked in CXX instead of finding it's own? I know it works now, just wondering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This Makefile uses [implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html) which are a great way to reduce duplication.

By default the first target will be built, here `all`. It depends on a number
of object files listed in a variable `$OBJECTS`, e.g. `Proj2.o` who's
dependencies aren't listed in the Makefile. Now if make sees an input file in the current directory
with a matching name, e.g. `Proj2.cpp` it will try
to build `Proj2.o` from it (there are other implicit rules for sources in
other languages). `Proj2.o` would then be built by default with the command

```
$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o Proj2.o
```

where `$(CXX)` the name of the C++ compiler (`g++` in your case).

The explicit build step for `all` assembles all the object files into the
target executable.

Looking at above build command you'll notice a small problem in your Makefile. Since the flags to the C++ compiler are given in a variable `FLAGS` and not the standard `CXXFLAGS` no warnings will be emitted when building the object files. Using the standard name would fix this (you do want warnings, maybe even more than `-Wall` gives you).

Comment: Awesome thank you for the comment! Aside from this, going on what you wrote "$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o Proj2.o". I have changed my "FLAGS" variable to "CFLAGS" and I used the command "make" again, but the compiler did not use the CFLAGS flag's variables in making the .o objects. Is there a way to have it implicitly use flags without much overhead? Thank you in advance for your time.

Comment: @UnmercifulTurtle: I was editing in the meantime. `CFLAGS` is for the C compiler, `CXXFLAGS` for the C++ compiler. Since you compile C++ sources you'll need the latter. Also interesting is `LDFLAGS` which are the flags for the linker (but you have that step explicit in above example).

Comment: Thank you for the tip! Just made the changes and it works even better now, thanks :)

Comment: Great it helped. Since you are cleaning up why not rename `CC` to `CXX` as well since it points to a C++ compiler? With that I'd call that Makefile *clean*.

Comment: Awesome, just did that! This Makefile is certainly the best I've used, I will be using this format from here on out. If I could check-mark everyone in this thread I would, best cooperation on StackOverflow I've seen in a while :)

Comment: @UnmercifulTurtle: If that's the best you've seen so far, you have seen nothing yet. If you excuse me shamelessly advertising my own work, take a look at [OSDev Wiki: Makefile tutorial](http://wiki.osdev.org/Makefile), and once you're done, switch to [my preconfigured CMake setup](http://rootdirectory.de/wiki/JAWS) and never look back. ;-)

Comment: How does it know to use `$(CXX)` to link? Won't implicit rules just use `$(CC)`? It's just a bunch of object files, right?

Comment: @doug65536: The snippet in the answer is about the implicit rule creating the object files. The link step was explicit in the question and is using `$(CC)` (which is actually `g++`).

Answer (score 5):

Make has a set of implicit rules (see [here](http://ftp.gnu.org/old-gnu/Manuals/make-3.79.1/html_chapter/make_10.html) for a reference). For instance

```
Compiling C++ programs
`n.o' is made automatically from `n.cc' or `n.C' with a command of the form 
`$(CXX) -c $(CPPFLAGS)   $(CXXFLAGS)'.
```

Most make's will also use this rule for .cpp files.
When make sees there's a x.o requirement for one of your targets, it will try to see if it can generate x.o using implicit rules, and in your case find it can do it starting from a .cpp file.